# Namespace.GetItemFromId Exception

Tags: c++, outlook

When I try to process incoming emails (whithin `NewMailEx` method) I got an exception if I call the `GetItemFromId` method (an access violation). Doesn't `Namespace.GetItemFromId` method require storeId as a second parameter? what value should I prvide as a store Id in case I'm not interested in which Inbox the event was raised. In other words I want only to retreive informations about the received email regardless which account (inbox) it belongs to.

```
CMailItem m_mailItem = NULL;
CApplication l_application;
l_application.CreateDispatch("Outlook.Application");
CNameSpace l_namespace = l_application.GetNamespace(_T("MAPI"));
CString ItemId((pDispParams->rgvarg)->bstrVal);
m_mailItem = l_namespace.GetItemFromID(ItemId, /*whatIdToProvide*/??);
```

I tried to pass an emty value but this didn't work.

Here is the GetItemFromId definition (automatically generated)

```
LPDISPATCH GetItemFromID(LPCTSTR EntryIDItem, const VARIANT& EntryIDStore)  
{   
        LPDISPATCH result;
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR VTS_VARIANT;
    InvokeHelper(0x2109, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_DISPATCH, (void*)&result, parms,EntryIDItem, &EntryIDStore);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all optional parameters, you need to pass a variant of type VT_ERROR with the value of  DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dmitry, the excepion is now more thrown. Now how can I check whether the received item is a mailItem?

Comment: You can explicitly QueryInterface() for the IMailItem interface. Or read the Class property using IDIspatch::GetIDsOfNames/Invoke.